# Future(<not completed>) when Future.map Combinator Used

Tags: scala, future

After using a `Future.map` to process the first `Future`, the second dependent `Future` is always `Future(<not completed>)` once `Future.onComplete` is called back.  Other constructions using two `Future`s never exhibit this behaviour.

Can anyone explain why `Future.onComplete` is being called although the future is apparently not complete?

Scala 2.12.3 is used.  Cut and paste the following to evaluate this problem, if needed.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}


object FutureNotCompleted {

  def threadNumber: String = f"${Thread.currentThread().getId.toInt}%2d"

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Future completion control
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var futures: ListBuffer[Future[Any]] = ListBuffer()

  def add(future: Future[Any]): Unit = synchronized(futures += future)

  def remove(future: Future[Any]): Unit = synchronized(futures = futures.filter(_ != future))

  def loopTillCompleted: Unit = {
    var futuresOnList = true;

    while (futuresOnList) {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      for (future <- futures) {
        if (future.isCompleted) {
          future.value.get match {
            case Success(v) => println(s"${threadNumber} Success: ${v}")
            case Failure(e) => println(s"${threadNumber} Error: ${e}")
          }
          remove(future)
        }
      }
      if (futures.size == 0) futuresOnList = false
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Future factory
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  def createRegisteredFuture: Future[Int] = {
    val future = createFuture
    add(future)
    future
  }

  def createFuture: Future[Int] = Future {
    val i = (Math.random() * 1000).toInt
    println(s"${threadNumber} Future work start: ${i}")
    Thread.sleep((Math.random() * 1000).toLong)
    println(s"${threadNumber} Future work stop:  ${i}")
    if (Math.random > 0.7) throw new RuntimeException(s"${threadNumber} Error for ${i}")
    i
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Functions exhibiting Future use conditions
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  def futureDoesNotComplete: Unit = {

    val f1 = createRegisteredFuture
    val f2 = f1.map {
      i => createRegisteredFuture
    }
    // This is never completed at the time the 'onComplete' callback is called
    f2.onComplete({
      case Success(j) => println(s"${threadNumber} j: ${j} ")
      case Failure(e) => println(s"${threadNumber} f2 Failure: ${e}")
    })

    loopTillCompleted
    println(s"${threadNumber} All done.")
  }

  def futureCompletes: Unit = {

    val f1 = createRegisteredFuture

    f1.onComplete({
      case Success(i) => {
        val f2 = createRegisteredFuture
        f2.onComplete({
          case Success(j) => println(s"${threadNumber} i: ${i} j: ${j} ${i}+${j}=${i + j}")
          case Failure(e) => println(s"${threadNumber} f2 Failure: ${e}")
        })
      }
      case Failure(e) => println(s"${threadNumber} f1 Failure: ${e}")
    })

    loopTillCompleted
    println(s"${threadNumber} All done.")
  }

  def futureCompletesFor: Unit = {

    for {
      f1 <- createRegisteredFuture
      f2 <- createRegisteredFuture
    } yield {
      println(s"f1: ${f1} f2: ${f2}: f1+f2=${f1+f2}")
    }

    loopTillCompleted
    println(s"${threadNumber} All done.")
  }

  def main(a: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //    futureCompletes
    futureDoesNotComplete
    //    futureCompletesFor
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the desired behavior here is exactly, but I would try flatMap here, you really want to onComplete the whole future chain I think. If this is the issue then you're just completing the outer future, and that's what I suspect since when you use for (which is working) it does the same as flatMap.

```
10 Future work start: 791
10 Future work stop:  791
11 Future work start: 819
11 Future work stop:  819
11 j: 819 
 1 Success: 791
 1 Success: 819
 1 All done.
```

I would change map to flatMap here, since createRegisteredFuture creates a future itself.

```
val f2 = f1.flatMap {
      i => createRegisteredFuture
}
```

Comment: I was working through examples on this page:  
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions.  

In the middle of that page one finds: 

`val rateQuote = Future {
  connection.getCurrentValue(USD)
}
val purchase = rateQuote map { quote =>
  if (isProfitable(quote)) connection.buy(amount, quote)
  else throw new Exception("not profitable")
}
purchase onSuccess {
  case _ => println("Purchased " + amount + " USD")
}`
Where `connection.buy` is a `Future`.  It appeared I had reproduced the example provided.  Perhaps not.

Comment: The main difference between that example and your example is that they have one more wrapping future in the callbacks example and then note that it goes away in the map example on that page. You're getting a Future[Future[Int]] when you do map in your code. You can validate this yourself if you explicitly set the type in `val f2: Future[Future[Int]] = ...`